# Store array in string backwards

Tags: javascript, html

I stored the array in a string backwards but it always has an 'undefined' in it. I dont know where its coming from. Heres how I do it:

```js
var jump = ['j', 'u', 'n', 'i', 'p', 'e', 'r'];
var rev;
var i = jump.length - 1;

while (i >= 0) {
    rev += jump[i];
    document.writeln(i.toString() + jump[i]);
    i--;
}

alert(rev.toString());
```

I tried this with `pop()` and `reverse()` and I still get the `undefined`.

Comment: change `var rev;` to `var rev = ""` or `var rev = []`

Comment: A `for` loop is better suited for that code. `for (i=jump.length-1;i>=0;i--)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since JS is dynamically typed, it doesn't know that `rev` is supposed to be a string, and so it will remain undefined until you initialize it with a value. Initialize `rev` like this:

```
var rev = "";
```

```js
var jump = ['j', 'u', 'n', 'i', 'p', 'e', 'r'];
var rev = "";
var i = jump.length - 1;
while (i >= 0) {
  rev += jump[i];
  document.writeln(i.toString() + jump[i]);
  i--;
}
alert(rev.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize rev with an empty string

like

```
var rev="";
```

```js
var jump = ['j', 'u', 'n', 'i', 'p','e','r'];
            var rev="";
            
            
            var i = jump.length - 1;



            while (i >= 0) {
                rev += jump[i];
                
                document.writeln(i.toString()+ jump[i]);
                i--;
            }


            alert(rev.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var jump = ['j', 'u', 'n', 'i', 'p','e','r'];
            var rev = [];
            
            
            var i = jump.length - 1;



            while (i >= 0) {
                rev += jump[i];
                
                document.writeln(i.toString()+ jump[i]);
                i--;
            }


            alert(rev.toString());
```

Comment: This code works because whenever it gets to the first `rev += jump[i];` it doesn't know how to add an array to a string, so it does a type conversion from empty array to empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This code have same result:

```
const jump = ['j', 'u', 'n', 'i', 'p','e','r'];                  
jump.forEach((e, i)=>document.writeln(""+i+e));
alert(jump.join(""));
```

or:

```
const jump = ['j', 'u', 'n', 'i', 'p','e','r'];
let rev = ""
jump.forEach(function(e, s){
    rev += e;
    document.writeln(""+s+e);  
})
alert(rev);
```

with store.